# storing persistent values under fire monkey with OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, ini, persistent-storage

Can someone bear with a MacOSX programming newbie?

This may be an obvious question but I can't seem to find the MacOSX equivalent of the Windows Tinifile in Delphi RADstudio 10.1 Berlin.

I want to store a number of settings when my app is closed so they can be reloaded the next time it is run.

I could use a database table but I would prefer to use a settings file.

I can't find any information on this

Thank you

Comment: [System.IniFiles.TIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile) is a subclass of `TMemIniFile` on non-windows platforms. I believe the `GetHomePath` will get you the directory to store the file.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realise I could still use inifiles

Answer (score 0):

> -This may be an obvious question but I can't seem to find the MacOSX equivalent of the Windows Tinifile in Delphi RADstudio 10.1 Berlin.

[System.IniFiles.TIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile) is a subclass of TMemIniFile on non-windows platforms:

> **Non-Windows Platforms**
>
> On non-Windows platforms, **TIniFile** is a subclass of TMemIniFile that has the AutoSave property always set to True. **TIniFile** writes data into the INI file either explicitly by calling UpdateFile or implicitly when the destructor is called. Last one happens when AutoSave and Modified are set to True.

Just use `TIniFile` on OSX as described above and it will work.

A suitable path to store the file might be found by calling [System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath).